# Read and save multiple sheet

Tags: r

I have found this code and I would like to save the different sheets in R from Excel, how can I change the code?

```
library(readxl)    
multiplesheets <- function(fname) {
   
  # getting info about all excel sheets
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(fname)
  tibble <- lapply(sheets, function(x) readxl::read_excel(fname, sheet = x))
  data_frame <- lapply(tibble, as.data.frame)
    
  # assigning names to data frames
  names(data_frame) <- sheets
    
  # print data frame
  print(data_frame)
}
  
# specifying the path name
path <- "/Users/mallikagupta/Desktop/Gfg.xlsx"
multiplesheets(path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `purrr::walk2()`

Since the output of `multiplesheets` is a list of sheets, you can use `walk2()` to walk across the list of sheets and a list of their names, saving each sheet by its name:

```r
sheets <- multiplesheets(path)

filenames <- paste0(names(sheets), ".csv")

## install.packages("purrr") #(if you haven't already)
purrr::walk2(sheets, filenames, write.csv) # or try readr::write_csv() for nicer output
```